# Getting path after document folder in ios development

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I need to have the path *after* **Document** folder of my application.

Consider I have this path : `myapp/sandbox/Documents/a/b/c/Documents/d/e/myfile.txt`.

I need a procedure to have this path: `a/b/c/Documents/d/e/myfile.txt`.

How can I get the second path?

Answer (score 3):

// Try this

```
NSString * str_DocDirPath  = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a/b/c/d/e/myfile.txt"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString * path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a/b/c/d/e/myfile.txt"];
```

Log this Path.

Try this code.